# Reducing my boost lib folder

Tags: c++, dynamic, boost, dll, static

Even having already dug through loads of info on the net about this, I am still having some trouble understanding the boost lib files. I have Boost 1.51 installed and the lib folder is 1.7GBs which is just too much. I need to reduce it.

Just to show an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec6se.png

That is all the regex lib folders. There are 10 of them! I want to delete most of these, but I struggle to understand, which folders I need.

I  assume 'libboost' is the static lib (which doesn't require a DLL) and the others are dynamic which do. Does it mean if I use the dynamic libraries I need boost DLLs in my project?

I can also see some are debug and others aren't. Is it necessary to keep both? or can I just always use the non-debug versions for my projects?

Finally, am I right in thinking, to make Visual Studio choose specific libs I go to the:
`C/C++ project settings -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library`, and change between /MT, /MD, etc?
If I use Multi-threaded (/MT), does that mean I can remove all the debug libs and dlls  because this option only uses the static libs?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: -mt is "multithreading", -s is "static", -gd is "debugging". Depending on whether or not you need to compile debug or static binaries you don't necessarily need all of these. But 1.7GB is not that much on any *halfway* modern machine (even a couple of generations back)?

Comment: Unfortunately I have plenty of restrictions to follow from the IT dept :( I know I can't reduce it dramatically but anything will help, as you can see in the image that is clearly too many copies.

Comment: I would like to avoid carrying DLLs around but still use release and debug mode in my programs so, If I keep the files tagged with 's' which are the mt-s and the mt-sgd lib files; That would cover me for the two modes in Runtime Library
Multi-threaded (/MT)
Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
 

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

> I assume 'libboost' is the static lib (which doesn't require a DLL) and the others are dynamic which do.

Yes.

> Does it mean if I use the dynamic libraries I need boost DLLs in my project?

Yes.

> Finally, am I right in thinking, to make Visual Studio choose specific libs I go to the: C/C++ project settings -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library, and change between /MT, /MD, etc?

Not quite so. Setting /MT or any other similar option will only make your application use the corresponding versions of runtime libraries (e.g. CRT). It does not mean you can only link statically after this, neither does it "select" anything for your own project-specific dependencies.

Whether you link to boost as a static library or DLL depends on which .lib file (libboostXXX or boostXXX) you specify in: **Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies**. Also, you may need to visit **Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories** and add a path to your boost/libs folder (and possibly its subfolders) so that you don't have to specify full path for each library you are adding to dependencies.

However, you should always (especially when using static libraries) link to libraries built with the same runtime which you have selected in your main project. If you try to mix different runtimes, you will most likely get pretty cryptic linker errors about double-defined symbols (in system libraries) and such. In the worst case (usually due to a mismatch in some less obvious settings, like preprocessor definitions that change STL options) it will not lead to a linker failure, but to mysterious runtime crashes. Visual Studio 2010 and later, however, does pretty good job of detecting such mismatches (compared to previous VS versions).

Another issue might be that some of the boost headers are using **#pragma comment** to force linking necessary libraries by a specific name. If you find this a problem and want to specify your dependencies manually (or if it selects something you don't really need to link to), you can add a global preprocessor define **BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB** to **C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions**.

Also, do you really need **all** of the boost libraries in your project? There's a lot of them, and most are for very special things. In my experience, people usually only need a small subset of boost for their project-specific goals. To create such a subset, containing headers only for the libraries which you really use, and their dependencies, you can use the [BCP utility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html). This would probably reduce your boost/boost folder dramatically. And, of course, you can also delete binaries for the libraries you are not going to use. Also note that most of the general-purpose libraries in boost are header-only and thus don't require linking to any libraries at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! my problem has been resolved :) I know this is kind of an old question, i'm very sure I replied to this ages ago.. but obviously not.